# How can I load models from sequelize-typescript with sequelize-cli?

Tags: nestjs, sequelize-cli, sequelize-typescript

I need to write a seeder that creates several models for the roles table, but if it doesn't exist I need to create a roles table. The table is already described but with sequelize-typescript. Question: How do I load a model from sequelize-typescript?

The code of the table itself:

```js
export class RoleCreationArgs {
    accessLevel: number;
    title: string;
}

@Table({ tableName: 'roles', timestamps: false })
export class Role extends Model<Role, RoleCreationArgs> {
    @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: Number, nullable: false, example: 1, description: "Unique id" })
    @Column({ type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, unique: true })
    id: number;

    @ApiProperty({ type: Number, nullable: false, example: 1 })
    @Column({ type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 1 })
    accessLevel: number;

    @ApiProperty({ type: String, nullable: false, example: "ADMIN", })
    @Column({ type: DataTypes.STRING, defaultValue: 'user' })
    title: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: User, isArray: true })
    @HasMany(() => User)
    users: User[]
}
```

I tried many variants like just import my Role model but it doesnt work. When I just try to import it, it says:
ERROR: Cannot find module '../../src/users/models/users.model'
Require stack:

- D:\projects\nest_forum\db\migrations\20230702152642-create-users-table.js
- D:\projects\nest_forum\node_modules\umzug\lib\migration.js
- D:\projects\nest_forum\node_modules\umzug\lib\index.js
- D:\projects\nest_forum\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\core\migrator.js
- D:\projects\nest_forum\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\commands\migrate.js
- D:\projects\nest_forum\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\sequelize